# In HTML, we don't have to specify the file extension of an image file?

Tags: html

For a long time, I have been using

> http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401

as an image, but I just checked that http://www.w3.org/Icons doesn't actually have that file or folder, but several images with the name `valid-html401.___` such as gif or png.

So it is surprising: seems like for a long time (even if IE 6), we can specify an image `<img src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401">` without the file extension of the image file?  What's the rule?

Comment: +1 for asking a good question which solicited some informative responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is: URLs are not filenames.

The data type is determined by the Content-Type HTTP response header, not the format of the URL.

Web servers can decide what content to serve up (and what Content-Type header to send) for a given URL however they like.

*Map URIs directly onto the filesystem and determine the content type from the extension* is just a simple and common approach.

Other options include [Apache Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) and using a programming language (usually with a framework such as [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)) to decide using whatever custom logic you like.

Comment: let's say, if I am serving that image on dreamhost.com, `valid-html5.png`, I must include the `.png` part or else the image appears as a missing image?

Comment: If the server is configured to only use the basic *map URIs directly onto the filesystem and determine the content type from the extension* approach to determining what content to server — yes.

Answer (score 1):

You're making an HTTP GET. The response will include a content type in the header (e.g. image/jpeg), the filename is just there really for human convenience. Which is why /xxxxx.do URLs can return HTML etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is done on the server side, and not by the client. You don't need extensions for images, unless the image has an extension. There is no reason you cannot program 404 requests to search for a similar match and display it.

Comment: There is no 404 response involved in this case. The server simply gives a content-negotiated 200 response.